# Img animation script Uncaught TypeError in jQuery

Tags: jquery

im trying to create a script where are thumbnails and if user moves on the thumbnail then with jQuery script the image will be enlarged in new position, in `div` to be exact. So far i´ve managed to this far, and dont know why this script doesnt work, as soon as i move on the image the console `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.min.js:3` and the error amount gets infinite loop   :

Script :

```
$(function thumb_animation() {

        var thumb = $('.st_thumbs img');
        var img = $('#bigImg');

        console.log(thumb);
        thumb.on('mouseenter',function (e)
{
        var thumbSource = e.target.src;

    img.attr('src',thumbSource);
    img.show("fade", 2000);
    img.animate({height:'60%',width:'66%'}, {queue: false});


}); 

thumb.mouseleave(function() {

img.animate({height:'0%', width:'0%'}, {queue: false});

})
});
```

And HTML :

```
<div class='wrap'>  
<ul id="st_nav" class="st_navigation">
            <li class="album">
                <div class="st_wrapper st_thumbs_wrapper">
                    <div class="st_thumbs">
                        <?php showGallery(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li> 
        </ul>
 <div class='gallery'>
 <img id='bigImg' src='images/album/thumbs/2.jpeg'>
 </div>
```

Comment: What markup does the PHP script return? The markup you've shown so far doesn't include any elements that would be matched by the jQuery selector '.st_thumb img'.

Comment: This what the ` showGallery()`  outputs $galleryhtml ="<img src='$src'>"; echo $galleryhtml;  , by any elements that would be matched u mean ` <img> ?

Comment: In which case, I think you need `var thumb = $('.st_thumbs img');` - you're missing an "s"

Comment: Oh thanks, now atleast i am gettinig  `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and it gets into infinte loop (error amount)

Comment: Interesting , i changed jQuery version to 1.9.1 and it start working.